# How to get on ubuntu terminal a progressbar for fstrim

Tags: command-line, trim

Sometime if you run the follow on terminal, it can take some time, depend on the space which will be trimmed.

```
sudo fstrim -v /
```

How to get a progressbar for this.

Result of my research:

Progressbar are possible in some other cases:

- https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/pv/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20220922104202/https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/pv/
- https://scheible.it/fortschrittsanzeige-dd/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20220920204015/https://scheible.it/fortschrittsanzeige-dd/

Answer (score 5):

You can make your own function that draws a progress bar while it waits for the previous job to complete:

```bash
# Function to show progbar while running command in the background
show_progbar() {
  # Uses PID of previous command, unless PID is given as 1st parameter
  if [[ -z $1 ]]
  then
    PID=$!
  else
    PID=$1
  fi
  ii=0
  jj=0
  bar="="       # Character to draw
  echo -n " [ "

  # While the process with PID is running, progbar is drawing
  while [[ -d "/proc/$PID" ]]
  do
    printf "%b" "\b${bar}]"
    (( ii++ ))
    sleep .1    # Speed of the progress bar
  done
  (( ii=ii+3 ))

  # Erases the progress bar after it is done
  while [[ $jj -lt $ii ]]
  do
    printf "\b"
    (( jj++ ))
  done
}
```

This must be defined or sourced in your shell (or script). To use it run the command like:

```
sudo fstrim -v / & \
show_progbar
```

*(The backslash is needed to line break when ran from the shell - it can be omitted in a script.)*

Comment: That looks cool. And allows for a lot of tweaking.